# ¿Es posible hacer interactuar a dos paginas HTML usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Por ejemplo: Tengo 2 paginas HTML. En la pagina 1 tengo un texto. En la Pagina 2 tengo un botón. ¿Es posible, que al hacer Click al botón de la pagina 2 el texto de la pagina 1 cambie por otro texto diferente?

Comment: Podrías usar localStorage, pero sin saber a ciencia cierta tu avance, no es adecuado darte una respuesta. Por favor revisa [ask]

Comment: Deberías aclarar que son dos páginas para ti, dar más detalles y por supuesto, aportar tus intentos.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que para implementar esa funcionalidad en dos paginas con el mismo origen utilizases la API de [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Así mientras en una seteas un valor al hacer click en el botón

```
localStorage.setItem("click","ok")
```

en la otra verificas si se seteó ese valor en un intervalo

```
var interval=setInterval(()=>{
    if (localStorage.getItem("click")) {
        //clearInterval(interval);
        localStorage.removeItem("click")
        console.log("Boton pulsado");
    }
}, 500);
```